# CSS Grid animations doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, animation, css-grid

How can I make an animation with CSS Grid in Chrome? This is a simple style using `Grid`, it change the `grid-template-columns` when the element has `active` class. It works in Firefox. But... In Chrome it doesn't. Is it posible?

```
#app {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 90px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 60px auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "menu contenido";
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
#app.active {
    grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  }
```

And here the onclick event.

```js
document.getElementById('app').classList.toggle('active');
```

Answer (score 6):

Short answer, **no**, this isn't possible in Chrome as of today

Firefox shipped animation of `grid-template-columns` in Firefox 66, but the Chromium team hasn't implemented it yet.

I included an image from MDN with the current support for animating `grid-template-columns`.

If you want to look up animatable CSS properties, [MDN has a good list here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

If you click on a specific property you can scroll down and see what browser support they have.

[image]